# In jmeter websocket request shown run as sucessfully but request ping is not shown in aws logs as it fail. How can we run webscoket using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter websocket request shown run as sucessfully but request ping is not shown in aws logs as it fail. How can we run webscoket using jmeter.

[Request response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F285k.png)

[Request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUJ9u.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETYXl.png)

[AWS Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeGwK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have successfully executed the request (from JMeter perspective)

If you want to try troubleshooting the issue from JMeter side you could [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the WebSocket Samplers plugin by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change, once done you should be able to see all request and response details in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

Both *log4j2.xml* and *jmeter.log* files should live in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

Comment: I check jmeter logs but not found any solutions there. Here I am attaching aws with question if know any thing about that then please let me know.     [2022-02-11 06:47:43 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Error handling request /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=QY-gDR9ILS5J4CauAASk

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle

Comment: Not found any solution by above mentioned answer. Could you please let me know other way out if any body know.